# Exercise about Hodge Star Operator on $\Lambda^{p,q}$

Tags: differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory

In real case, $$ \ast (e_1\cdots e_k)=e_{k+1}\cdots e_n$$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $e_i$ is $1$-form and $e_1\cdots e_n$ is volume on $\mathbb{R}^n$

We will extend to **complex** case. Define $$ dz_k:= e_k + ie_{n+k} $$ On $\mathbb{C}^n=\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ we have a **volume** form : $$ dv:= e_1e_{n+1}\cdots e_n e_{2n} $$

Hence we have for instance : $$ 
\ast (dz_1)=e_{n+1}e_2\cdots e_{2n} - i e_1e_2\cdots e_{2n} $$
 That is, $\ast$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear.

**Problem** : We want to prove that $$ \ast : \Lambda^{p,q}\rightarrow \Lambda^{n-q,n-p} $$ where $\Lambda^{p,q}$ is a space of elements of $$\alpha :=dz_{i_1}\cdots dz_{i_p}d\overline{z}_{j_1}\cdots d\overline{z}_{j_q} $$

**Proof** : (1) Note that $$ \frac{i}{2} dz_1d\overline{z}_1
= e_1e_{n+1} $$ so that $$ 
dv = (\frac{i}{2})^n dv_0,\ dv_0:= dz_1d\overline{z}_1
\cdots 
dz_nd\overline{z}_n $$

Hence we have a map $f$ s.t. $$ A\in \mathbb{C},\ f (A\alpha )=A f(\alpha),\ 
\alpha f(\alpha)=dv_0 $$

(2) If $n=1$, $$ \ast dz_1=-idz_1 $$

Hence problem holds.

(3) If $n=2,\ a=dz_2$ then by direct computation $$ 
\ast a = C_1 dz_1 d\overline{z}_1 
dz_2 = C_2\overline{ f(a)} $$ for some $C_i\in \mathbb{C}$.

But general case, I have no idea. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the Hodge star operator depends on the definition of the $L^2$ inner product, which depends on the definition of the metric on the exterior algebra $\bigwedge^{\bullet} (T^*M)$ on a compact oriented real manifold $M$.

Take a section $\chi_1,\dots,\chi_n$ of $T^*M$, then for each $\mathbb{Z}\ni k>1$, the $k$-forma $\chi_{i_1}\wedge\cdots\chi_{i_k}$, where $1\leq i_1<\cdot<i_n\leq n$ are strictly increasing sequences of $k$-tuples in $[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$ form a basis for $\bigwedge^k(T^* M)$.

Then, if we require that basis to be orthonormal if $\chi_1,\dots,\chi_n$ forms an orthonormal frame on $T^*M$. We can extend by bilinearity to a non-degenerate inner product on $\bigwedge^k(T^*M)$. One can show (using the Cauchy-Binet formula), that if $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k,\beta_1,\dots,\beta_k$ are in $T_p^*M$, then

$$\langle \alpha_1\wedge\dots\wedge \alpha_k,\beta_1\wedge\dots\beta_k\rangle = \det((\langle\alpha_i,\beta_j\rangle)_{i,j\in [k]})$$

Since, $M$ is oriented if and only if there exists a unique $n$-form $\Omega$ that is $1$ on every positively oriented orthonormal basis of $T_pM$.

We define $*$ to be such that, for $k$-forms $\alpha,$ and $\beta$

$$\alpha\wedge *\beta = \langle \alpha,\beta\rangle\Omega$$

Now, since the manifold $M$ is compact, the integral
$$(\alpha,\beta):= \int_M \alpha\wedge *\beta = \int_M \langle\alpha,\beta\rangle \Omega$$
is a positive definite inner product on $k$-forms.

Now, here's the **crucial observation**, when we extend this inner product from real forms to complex forms, we need to add complex conjugation to the second factor to keep it positive definite. So, on $A^k(M,\mathbb{C})$ the space of sections of the $k^{\rm th}$ exterior power of the cotangent bundle with complex coefficients, the $L^2$ inner product is,
$$(\alpha,\beta):= \int_M \alpha\wedge \overline{*\beta}$$

Now, we need $\overline{*\beta}$ to be a $(n-p,n-q)$-form for $\alpha\wedge \overline{*\beta}$ to be a $2n-$form which is the desired real dimension of the manifold $M$, such that $M$ has complex dimension $n$.

Since, complex conjugation sends $(i,j)-$forms to $(j,i)-$forms. $*\beta$ has to be an $n-q,n-p$ form!